# Div position pusing content

Tags: html, css, position

I am having trouble aligning my div so it doesn't push content below down, somehow if the asset name is more than one row, it will push down the metadata description down one row, I have tried positioning and flow and it seems now working, could some one please take a look to see what I have done wrong?

CSS

```
.port-container {
width: 490px;
height: 166px;
margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
float: left;
}

.port-container .port-image-link {
position: relative;
left: 10px;
}

.port-container .port-metadata-text {
padding: 50px 12px 10px 50px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #000;
font-size: 12px;  
position: absolute;
margin-top: -180px;
margin-left: 173px;
z-index: 8;
line-height: 17px;
}
.port-container .port-image-link .port-text-link {
cursor: pointer;
width: 220px;   
top: 138px;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
z-index: 9;
}

.port-container .port-image-link a {
text-decoration: none;
}

.port-container .port-image-link a span.port-text-link {
color: #fff;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height: 17px;
position: relative;
top: -170px;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 9px 50px 0px 0px;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
left: 220px;
display: block;
}
.port-container .port-image-link a:hover span.port-text-link {
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="port-container">    
<div class="port-image-link">
%asset_thumbnail%<a href="%asset_url%"><span class="port-text-link">%asset_name%</span></a>
<div class="port-metadata-text">%asset_metadata_DC.Description%</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if if seems to be working what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Thanks, if the %asset_name% text length is more than 220px it will be pushed into the second row, then the %asset_metadata_DC.Description% will be pushed one row down, the problem is some %asset_name% is within 220px and some not, I want a consistency of  %asset_metadata_DC.Description% stay at the same position regardless of whether %asset_name% is long or short